# (WIN32) Using header guards is crashing my program

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently making a win32 application, and for some reason when I use header guards nothing works the same way it will when I write console apps. 
At the top of my class files, I have a #ifndef XXX #define XXXXX #endif, which I was Taught was necessary to avoid including files multiple times. However, this makes it so none of my classes can be seen!

I can't even declare a class in the .h file and define it in a .cpp file, the .cpp file won't be able to find the class definition! Which is weird, because when I right click on an instance of the class that I've written in the .cpp file and click "go to declaration", it takes me to the right .h file! How can visual studio take me to it but not know where it is?

here is code

```
    //ProgramWindows.h


#ifndef PROGRAMWINDOWS_H
#define PROGRAMWINDOWS_H


#include <Windows.h>
//#include "ProcMainMenu.h"
#include "ProgramDefines.h"



class ProgramWindows
{

private:
    WNDCLASSEX mainwindow;
    WNDCLASSEX doublependulum;
    WNDCLASSEX wavesim2d;
    WNDCLASSEX wavesim3d;
    WNDCLASSEX springsim;
    WNDCLASSEX trajectorysim;


public:
    ProgramWindows();
    WNDCLASSEX & getMainWindow();
    WNDCLASSEX & getDoublePendWindow();
    WNDCLASSEX & get2DWaveWindow();
    WNDCLASSEX & get3DWaveWindow();
    WNDCLASSEX & getSpringWindow();
    WNDCLASSEX & getTrajecWindow();



};



#endif




    //ProgramWindows.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#include "ProgramDefines.h"
#include "ProgramWindows.h"
#include "ProcMainMenu.h"



ProgramWindows::ProgramWindows()
{

    //TODO: initialize all of the window member variables to their respective values that will be used in the program.
     this->mainwindow.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
     this->mainwindow.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC) ProcMainMenu;
     this->mainwindow.hInstance        = NULL;
     this->mainwindow.hbrBackground    = BACKGROUNDCOLOR;
     this->mainwindow.lpszClassName    = TEXT("WaveSimMain");

}

WNDCLASSEX & ProgramWindows::getMainWindow() 
{
    return this->mainwindow;
}

//.......... continued




    //ProcMainMenu.h
#ifndef PROCMAINMENU_H
#define PROCMAINMENU_H
/** This is the callback procedure for the main menu window of our program.
 *  From this window, the user is able to start any of the 5 sub-simulation programs
 *  contained in this project. This is basically the callback for the starting point of the
 *  program.
 */
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>


#include "ProgramDefines.h"
#include "ProgramWindows.h"



LRESULT CALLBACK ProcMainMenu( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{

     ProgramWindows *ptrWindows = new ProgramWindows();

    // switch on msg
    switch(msg)
    {



    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            //==========================
            // IMAGES FOR MAIN MENU BELOW
            //==========================

            //main menu title static box and image
            HWND MainMenuTitleBox = CreateWindowEx (NULL, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP, 80 , 0, 0, 0, hwnd, 0, NULL, NULL);
            HANDLE MainMenuTitleImage = LoadImage(NULL, L"C://Users//John//Documents//Visual Studio 2012//Projects//CS137 Project//CS137 Project//Pictures//MainMenu", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            SendMessage(MainMenuTitleBox, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) MainMenuTitleImage);




        }break; //end case WM_CREATE

    case WM_DESTROY:
        {

            delete ptrWindows; // delete the pointer to the ProgramWindows object


        }
        break;// end case WM Destroy


}// end ProcMainMenu




#endif




    //ProgramDefines.h
#ifndef PROGRAMDEFINES_H
#define PROGRAMDEFINES_H

/** This file is used to define aliases for all of the UI elements used in our file.
* In Windows Forms Applications, all UI elements must be represented by a unique interger, to
* allow our code to still be readable, we will define the names of the UI elements here and assign them
* to a unique interger. I don't really like it either, but it's the reccomended way of writing Windows Forms Applications,
* and allows for consistant definitions across all windows in the program
*
*/
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>


//#include "ProgramWindows.h"
//#include "ProcMainMenu.h"



//=========================
//=== COLORS ============
//========================

HBRUSH BACKGROUNDCOLOR = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,102));// deep blue
HBRUSH TEXTCOLOR = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255)); //white  



#endif
```

Comment: Dude - show us one of the guards that "isn't working".  You should be able to define the class in a header (.h) file.  The .h is the only file that has the guard.  The source (.cpp) file #include's the header.  It should all "just work".  I suspect the problem might be syntax in your .h...

Comment: It sounds like you might be using the same include guard in each header.  The code may be ifdefed all except in the first header included.

Comment: I'm definitely only using #ifndef,#define,#endif in the .h files, and I'm definitely using different names for each header gaurd. I thought I was doing cyclin includes but I'm not, I'm getting some damned cryptic error

Comment: You're not using `#ifdef` by mistake are you? :)

Comment: definitely not using #ifdef

Comment: Edited to include my code, check OP

Answer (score 2):

SORRY GUYS! I forgot a brace on one of my functions. This caused everything to crash and for me to get horrific errors